# Зачем используют ADASYN / SMOTE?(over-sampling -- imbalanced learn)

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение, dataframe

У нас есть какой-то датасет.

Например, датасет с характеристиками телефонов,названием и ценой.

Когда и для чего применяется SMOTE или ADASYN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это методы, которые используются для решения задач классификации в случае разбалансированной выборки. Именно для того, что-бы вводя искусственные, дополнительные точки снизить разбалансировку, проще говоря - увеличить количество точек менее мощного класса.

Понять, является-ли ваша выборка сбалансированной или разбалансированной по ЕДИНСТВЕННОМУ примеру - мне кажется даже задавать такой вопрос несколько странно. Соответственно, и принять решение об обоснованности применения указанных методов - невозможно.

Comment: Спасибо.В данном случае было целью просто узнать,для чего используют.Датасет вообще не нужен тут